# Group all results by parent in doctrine2, symfony2

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to retrieve all the entities of a table but grouped by their parent in arrays

if i have a category that has a parent category, something like:

```
id
name
parent
```

I want the results grouped by parent.. so i can work with them like:

```
array(
  0 => array(
          array(
            id => 1, 
            name => name1), 
          array(
            id => 2, 
            name => name2)),
  1 => array(
          array(
            id => 3, 
            name => name3), 
          array( 
            id => 4, 
            name => name4)))
```

and so on... is there something that let me work like that?

Comment: Is parent a simple field or a field that references another table? (Like categories and products)

Comment: parent is the field that represent the ID of the same table. (like categories, and parent should be the parent of that category)

Comment: Seems to be a interesting question. If your problem were Categories referencing Subcategories (not Categories referencing Categories) I'd advice you to get the Categories and loop over them to get the Subcategories referenced by each Category. Hummmm, let me think...

Comment: I think there is a possibility. If you `SELECT` the `DISTINCT` `parent` field and then loop over them (maybe with lazy loading feature) to retrieve all results with each parent... Could work?

Comment: finally done it this way... i know is not the best.. but works:

$metas = $dealFlowCMM->findBy(array(
   'communityMedia' => $cores,
   'typeMeta'       => $type,
   'parent'         => null));

  foreach ($metas as $meta) {
   $meta->children = $dealFlowCMM->findBy(array(
    'parent' => $meta->getId()),
   array('id' => 'DESC'));
   $media[] = $meta;
   
  }

Answer (score 0):

finally managed it this way... is not the best, but works for now:

```
$metas = $CMMRepo->findBy(array(
            'communityMedia' => $cores,
            'typeMeta'       => $type,
            'parent'         => null));

foreach ($metas as $meta) {
    $meta->children = $CMMRepo->findBy(array(
        'parent' => $meta->getId()),
         array('id' => 'DESC'));
    $media[] = $meta;

}
```

notice the "children"